# Extending Existing Interface Design

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have several classes which implement some interface, and instead of modifying it, I want to extend it with another interface.

When I'm thinking about designing the extending interface I'm not sure what is the best practice of how to include a reference to the original interface?

Id reference or include it as a property of the extending interface?

I've created an example below to show the need:

```
public interface IMovie
{
    string UniqueId { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    string Ratnig { get; set; }
}

//Option #1
public interface IMovieWithSubTitles
{
    string UniqueId { get; set; }

    string SubTitles { get; set; }
}

//Option #2
public interface IMovieWithSubTitles
{
    IMovie Movie { get; set; }

    string SubTitles { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Third option (inheritance):

```
interface IMovieWithSubTitles : IMovie 
{
     string SubTitles { get; set; }
}
```

Your first one just declares a *separate* interface. The second one *aggregates* `IMovie`. Both cases do not *extend* `IMovie`.

Comment: mmm... didn't know that one :) looks like this is the one I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I would have inherited `IMovie` with the new interface, such as

```
public interface IMovieWithSubTitles : IMovie 
{
    string SubTitles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to answer, but Dennis was faster so he'll get the answer check mark in 5 minutes :)

Comment: yeah, i noticed his answer while I was already typing, so I finished it anyway. Thanks.